# How can I hide or remove the content outside the input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to target the content and making the entire input fields hidden or disable specifically the field `"Pickup in Store : $0.00"`.

I can only get the radio button to be hidden but not the text beside the radio button. I know the Labels are global containers but I can see the input fields has a unique `ID`.  Is there a way we can accomplish this e.g. CSS, Javascript or Jquery?

```
<div class="shopping-basket-shipping-methods" data-shopping-basket-id="35838">
      <label class="user-form-field-label">
      <input class="shopping-basket-shipping-method" data-cart-id="411539" data-shopping-basket-id="35838" id="shopping_baskets_attributes_35838_shipping_method_id_932" name="shopping_baskets_attributes[35838][shipping_method_id]" type="radio" value="932">
          Canada Post - Ground : $20.00
      </label><br>
      <label class="user-form-field-label">
       <input checked="checked" class="shopping-basket-shipping-method" data-cart-id="411539" data-shopping-basket-id="35838" id="shopping_baskets_attributes_35838_shipping_method_id_915" name="shopping_baskets_attributes[35838][shipping_method_id]" type="radio" value="915">
      <p>Pickup in Store : $0.00</p>

      </label><br>
</div>
```

Comment: You can assign dynamic id for the label same as you did for the input field and use that to hide/show the label.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I see three options;

- Wrapping both elements in a single div and targeting them together (most straight foward)
- Targeting the previous sibling as well (not difficult with css)
- Assigning the label an equally descriptive and dynamic `id` for easier targeting (might require a bit of extra work)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the label element to wrap the radio and the text.

```
<div class="form-control">
  <label for="option1">Option 1 description</label>
  <input type="radio" name="shopping" id="option1" value="option1">
</div>
<div class="form-control">
  <label for="option2">Option 2 description</label>
  <input type="radio" name="shopping" id="option2" value="option2">
</div>
```

If you want to relate some text to an input field you can simply add a label element as a sibling of the input element and relate them with the `for` attribute matching the input's id that's going the make the html structure more solid, you can also use an extra class or add an id for the form-controls div to make it easier to select or if you are already using jQuery you can target these elements parent with something like `$('#option1').parent()`

Answer (score 0):

No need to hide all the `label` simply hide its content considering the ID of the input:

```css
#shopping_baskets_attributes_35838_shipping_method_id_915,
#shopping_baskets_attributes_35838_shipping_method_id_915 + *{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="shopping-basket-shipping-methods" data-shopping-basket-id="35838">
      <label class="user-form-field-label">
      <input class="shopping-basket-shipping-method" data-cart-id="411539" data-shopping-basket-id="35838" id="shopping_baskets_attributes_35838_shipping_method_id_932" name="shopping_baskets_attributes[35838][shipping_method_id]" type="radio" value="932">
          Canada Post - Ground : $20.00
      </label><br>
      <label class="user-form-field-label">
       <input checked="checked" class="shopping-basket-shipping-method" data-cart-id="411539" data-shopping-basket-id="35838" id="shopping_baskets_attributes_35838_shipping_method_id_915" name="shopping_baskets_attributes[35838][shipping_method_id]" type="radio" value="915">
      <p>Pickup in Store : $0.00</p>

      </label><br>
</div>
```